# What is the name of this piecewise probability mass function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am developing an RL algorithm with a policy that needs to compute valid probabilities over multiple distinct action sets. I think I have a construction that will work, but I do not know what it is called, or if it even has a name:

Given two probability mass functions $p_{\,A}$ and $p_{\,B}$, a probability mass function $p_{\, A \cup B}$ is defined:

$$
\begin{equation}
p_{\, A \cup B}(x) = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        m_{\, 1} \cdot p_{\, A}(x) & x \in A\\
        m_{\, 2} \cdot p_{\, B}(x) & x \in B
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}
$$
where $m_{\, 1} + m_{\, 2} = 1$, $m_{\, i} \geq 0$, and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

The proof that this is a valid pmf is simple:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{x \, \in \, A \cup B} p_{\, A \cup B}\,(x) &= \sum_{a \, \in \, A}m_{\, 1} \cdot p_{\, A}(a) \, + \, \sum_{b \, \in \, B} m_{\, 2} \cdot p_{\, B}(b) \\
&= m_{\, 1} \cdot \sum_{a \, \in \, A} p_{\, A}(a) \, + \, m_{\, 2} \cdot \sum_{b \, \in \, B} p_{\, B}(b) \\ 
&= m_{\, 1} \, + \, m_{\, 2} \\
&= 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
It doesn't look like a mixture distribution due to the splitting behavior. Again, I'm curious if this has a name, or what other constructions to which it might be related. Thank you.

Comment: Just set $p_{A}(b) = 0$ for all $b\in B$, $p_{B}(a) = 0$ for all $a \in A$ and you get a mixture. With that it seems to me kind of unnecessary to give it a separate name.

Comment: As $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, it is a mixture.